# Add a Linux distro from another without USB

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, windows, multiboot

I'm currently dual-booting Win 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I used my last flash drive for Ubuntu and I'd like to keep it. I'd also like to try some other Linux distros such as Manjaro and Mint Cinnamon. Can I simply install one Linux distro from another? Seems straightforward, but is it more trouble than it's worth?
I don't care about /home and sharing files and swap areas I just want to know in simple terms how to install another Linux distro.
Please advise thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- The most straight-forward way is to get a new USB pendrive.
- But I use USB pendrives as temporary devices. I store the iso files, that are still interesting, and when I want to test a linux distro in some computer, I clone from the iso file to a USB pendrive - In other words, you can re-use your pendrive several times, and need not be afraid of removing ubuntu from it. When the pendrive gets tired and slow, you can [wipe the whole device with mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe) in order to refresh it.
- You can also create a [menuentry for your iso file in your grub menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot). This way you can boot directly from the iso file. (But it might be difficult to find the command lines to boot linux distros, that are new for you.)
- You can use one of the available tools to create a multiboot USB drive. In this case the tool provides the command lines to boot into several linux distros.

  - [Ventoy](https://ventoy.net/en/index.html)
  - [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
  - [MultibootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/)